# java dynamic array creation

Tags: java, arrays

I've a situation where i am plotting graph using Aspose library. I created a graph but i hardcoded everything like arrays and column names when filling those arrays. I've given a task to make that process dynamic and read everything from database. I have total record size stored in `count` variable, which helped me to initialize array of that size. I also have information about number of arrays to be created stored as `columnCount`. With this information `count` and `columnCount`, how can i create arrays since i'll not be hardcoding them now. It will be created inside this block.

```
for(int i=0; i<columnCount; i++){
       //double type array will be initialized here. each of size count. 
     }
```

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ResultSet rs = ReportHandler.getQueryResult();
    rs.last();
    // get total number of records for array size.
    int count = rs.getRow();
    // this count will tell number of arrays to be created.
    int columnCount = ReportHandler.getCount("035","005");

    // this was static code. now i need to make it dynamic.
     double[] policyYear = new double[count];
     double[] commPremium = new double[count];

     for(int i=0; i<columnCount; i++){
       //double type array will be initialized here. each of size count. 
     }

     rs.beforeFirst();

     int j=0;
     // now i've a result set
     while(rs.next()){
       //static code, need to make it dynamic,
      policyYear[j] = rs.getDouble("policy_year");
      commPremium[j] = rs.getDouble("commulative_premium");
      j++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

Comment: You don't want `while(rs.next()){` inside the for loop. I guess you want the call to `next()` in the `ForUpdate`, i.e. `j++, rs.next()`.

Comment: @Logan no i didn't tried ArrayList. Will it help??

Comment: You mean you want to dynamically create `policyYear`, `commPremium` etc ? In the below answer you mentioned that you know the size, so you can Array or List. But I think your question is different.You need to rephrase your question and explain clearly what you mean by 'make it dynamic' ?

Comment: @KarthikR yeah i know size but i don't know number of arrays required. This array creation process should be dynamic. Like `policyYear`, `commPrem` arrays is just an example. Next time may be i need more than or less than two arrays for my process. Let me rephrase my question.

Comment: You can follow the answer of @DVK. The second part of  answer `Map<String, List<Double>>`. Get the column name and put it in the map with key based  on column name.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have an array but don't know its size, you can use [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class, which behaves like an array but is dynamically sized.

Use `.add()` method to add items to your arrays.

**UPDATE**

As per comment, user needs to have dynamic list of arrays.

So... - use ArrayList of ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> data = new ArrayList<>();
// ....
data.get(colIndex).set(rowIndex, rs.getDouble(colNameByIndex()));
   // assumes get(colIndex) is  not NULL - fix in real code
```

Or HashMap of ArrayLists

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Double>> data = new HashMap<>();
// ....
data.get(colName).set(rowIndex, rs.getDouble(colName));
   // assumes get(colName) is  not NULL - fix in real code
```

Comment: I know its size. i just don't know the number of arrays to be created. previously i declared two arrays (as you can see) but now i need to make it dynamic for my process.

Comment: @WajeehaFarooqi - that wasn't clear from the question

Comment: what's columnIndex and rowIndex?? you're referring to the variable `j` that i've used?